# Angular directive not executed on ionic modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I've created a really basic Angular Directive

```
 angular.module('starter.directives', [])
    .directive('imageRotate', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            console.log(1);
            debugger;
            elem.on('load', function() {
                var w = $(this).width(),
                    h = $(this).height();

                var div = elem.parent();

                //check width and height and apply styling to parent here.
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then in my controller I show the following modal

```
    <ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeLogin()">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <img ng-src="{{img}}" style="width: 100%" imageRotate />
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

I've incuded the module starter.directives in the starter module declaration.

When I show the modal, the directive is never executed.

This is how I show the modal

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl("../templates/galleryModal.html", {
                animation: 'slide-in-up',
                scope: $scope
            }).then(function(modal){
                $scope.modal = modal;
                $scope.modal.show();
            });
```

Any idea??

Comment: In the HTML you can't use camelCase to call the directive. Change it to: `<img ng-src="{{img}}" style="width: 100%" image-rotate />`.

Comment: Thanks you! As you said it was a naming problem.